# Cant parse JSON (nested dictionary) into ForEach with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, codable

I want to parse the following JSON into a list with SwiftUI, however I am experiencing some issues with this.

JSON (there are many more entires than this with random Identifiers as the entry. This is what caused it to be much harder to perform):

```json
{
  "DCqkboGRytms": {
    "name": "graffiti-brush-3.zip",
    "downloads": "5",
    "views": "9",
    "sha256": "767427c70401d43da30bc6d148412c31a13babacda27caf4ceca490813ccd42e"
  },
  "gIisYkxYSzO3": {
    "name": "twitch.png",
    "downloads": "19",
    "views": "173",
    "sha256": "aa2a86e7f8f5056428d810feb7b6de107adefb4bf1d71a4ce28897792582b75f"
  },
  "bcfa82": {
    "name": "PPSSPP.ipa",
    "downloads": "7",
    "views": "14",
    "sha256": "f8b752adf21be6c79dae5b80f5b6176f383b130438e81b49c54af8926bce47fe"
  }
}
```

SwiftUI Codables:

```swift
struct Feed: Codable {
    let list: [FeedValue]
}

struct FeedValue: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name, downloads, views, sha256: String
}
```

JSON Fetch method (and parse):

```swift
func getFeeds(completion:@escaping (Feed) -> ()) {

    // URL hidden to respect API privacy
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
        
        let feed = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Feed.self, from: data!)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(feed)
        }
        
    }.resume()
    
}
```

Finally, the view containing my ForEach loop:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollViewContentOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    
    @State var listFeed = Feed(list: [])
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // Z-coord status bar holder
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: true, contentOffset: $scrollViewContentOffset) {
                
                
                // Public files Start
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) { {
                    // Withholds our content for each asset retrieved.

                    // Main part
                    ForEach(listFeed.list, id: \.id) { download in
                        AssetView(name: .constant(download.name), downloads: .constant(download.downloads), views: .constant(download.views))
                    }

                }.padding([.leading, .top, .trailing], 25)
                // Public files End
                
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing, .top])
            
        }.background(Color.backgroundColor.ignoresSafeArea())
            .onAppear() {
                getFeeds { feed in
                    //print(feed) : this did happen to work at the time of testing
                    self.listFeed = feed
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

And for the error that is being presented:

**Starfiles/HomeView.swift:32: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "list", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "list", intValue: nil) ("list").", underlyingError: nil))**

I've spent several hours today changing the method of parsing, but was unable to find a solution on my own.

EDIT 1: I would like to mention that I need a way to access the dictionary ID's as well, as they'll be used for entering in a new view.

**EDIT 2: Using what @jnpdx provided, JSON parsing now works as expectedly, and gets the information I need. However there's an issue with ForEach loops, the same one which persisted before (It does work in a List(), as his answer showed).**

**Here is the updated code (not going to show any code that's irrelevant)**

```swift
                    ForEach(listItems) { item in // Cannot convert value of type '[IdentifiableFeedValue]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>' &  Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred
                        AssetView(name: .constant(item.feedValue.name), // Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Subject>' to expected argument type 'String'
    downloads: .constant(item.feedValue.downloads), views: .constant(item.feedValue.views))
                    }.onAppear() {
                        // URL hidden to respect API privacy, refer to JSON above.
                        guard let url = URL(string: "") else { return }
                        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
                            
                            do {
                                list = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:FeedValue].self, from: data!)
                            } catch {
                                print("error")
                            }
                            
                        }.resume()
                    }

// AssetView
struct AssetView: View {
    
    @Binding var name: String
    @Binding var downloads: String
    @Binding var views: String

...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't have any keys called `list`, which is why it's failing. Because it's a dynamically-keyed dictionary, you will want to decode it as `[String:FeedValue]`.

I used a wrapper to keep the `id` from the original JSON, but you could also do some fancier decoding if you wanted to keep it in a one-level `struct`, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

```
let jsonData = """
{
  "DCqkboGRytms": {
    "name": "graffiti-brush-3.zip",
    "downloads": "5",
    "views": "9",
    "sha256": "767427c70401d43da30bc6d148412c31a13babacda27caf4ceca490813ccd42e"
  },
  "gIisYkxYSzO3": {
    "name": "twitch.png",
    "downloads": "19",
    "views": "173",
    "sha256": "aa2a86e7f8f5056428d810feb7b6de107adefb4bf1d71a4ce28897792582b75f"
  },
  "bcfa82": {
    "name": "PPSSPP.ipa",
    "downloads": "7",
    "views": "14",
    "sha256": "f8b752adf21be6c79dae5b80f5b6176f383b130438e81b49c54af8926bce47fe"
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct FeedValue: Codable {
    let name, downloads, views, sha256: String
}

struct IdentifiableFeedValue : Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let feedValue: FeedValue
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var list : [String:FeedValue] = [:]
    
    var listItems: [IdentifiableFeedValue] {
        list.map { IdentifiableFeedValue(id: $0.key, feedValue: $0.value) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(listItems) { item in
            Text(item.feedValue.name)
        }.onAppear {
            do {
                list = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:FeedValue].self, from: jsonData)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had edited my post (EDIT 2) to fit what you've shown. This had resolved the parsing issue itself, and allowed me to access the ID as well. However it's unable to be used in a ForEach loop still.

Comment: Your code isn’t copy and pastable because of all the missing types. You’ll notice mine can be copied and pasted into a blank project and will work. You can replace my List with a ForEach inside a stack and it will continue to work.

Comment: It was my own problem, I realized I had binding setup and had to remove it.