# Parse Json file that has multi nest dictionary in Swiftui

Tags: json, dictionary, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays, nested-datalist

I have a Json file like this, I want to access to one (or random one) of the item in the list
(it is similar to the question at this [Cant parse JSON (nested dictionary) into ForEach with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72156399/cant-parse-json-nested-dictionary-into-foreach-with-swiftui))

```swift
{
    "school_1": [
        {
            "department": "Department A",
            "chairman": "Name of Mss",
            "location": "3rd Floor"
        },
        {
            "department": "Department B",
            "chairman": "Name of MssB",
            "location": "3rd Floor"
        }
    ],
    "school_2": [
        {
            "department": "Department AB",
            "chairman": "Name 2 ",
            "location": "Build A "
        },
        {
            "department": "Department ABC",
            "chairman": "Name 5 ",
            "location": "Build B "
        }
    ],
    "school_3": [
        {
            "department": "Department AB",
            "chairman": "Name 2 ",
            "location": "Build A "
        },
        {
            "department": "Department ABC",
            "chairman": "Name 5 ",
            "location": "Build B "
        }
    ],
    "school_A": [
        {
            "department": "Department AB",
            "chairman": "Name 2 ",
            "location": "Build A "
        },
        {
            "department": "Department ABC",
            "chairman": "Name 5 ",
            "location": "Build B "
        }
    ]
"_comment": "similar to 100th school for example"

}
```

I have tried to buil the models like this:

```swift
struct SchoolName: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let nameDepartment: Department
}

struct Department: Codable {
    let department: String
    let chairman: String
    let location: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case department = "department"
        case chairman = "chairman"
        case location = "location"
    }
}
```

I create this class to access to any school in the Json but I am not able to get it

```swift
class ReadJson: ObservableObject {

    @Published var listSchool: [String: Department] = [:]
    
    
    func fetchJson(fileJson: String, nameSchool: String) {
       
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileJson, withExtension: "json") else{
            fatalError("Could not find Json file")
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
           
             do {
                 let listSchool = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:Department].self, from: data)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
// I get stuck here that I don't know how to get data of one of any school
                  self.listSchool = SchoolName.nameSchool //??

                        }
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
              
        }
        task.resume()
    }//end func fetchJson
}
```